# A generic error occurred in GDi+ in deployed application but no error in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Good day, as the title explains, I have a pictureBox, when I browse for an image or capture an image from a webcam and display it to the picturebox, I also copy this image to a local folder in the computer.
All works in visual studio, I can capture or load an image an it save it in the folder.
When I deploy this software and install it in my development machine or an other machine, it load/capture the image and display it to the picturebox but fails to save it to local folder. It gives me an error: **A generic error occurred in GDi+**.
What could be the problem?

Here is the logfile:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException A generic error
>   occurred in GDI+.    at EduXpress.Program.<>c.b__0_0(Object
>   sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder,
>   EncoderParameters encoderParams)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)    at
>   EduXpress.Students.userControlStudentEnrolmentForm.btnBrowsePicture_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseControl.WndProc(Message& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    at
>   EduXpress.Program.Main()

This is the code:

```
 XtraOpenFileDialog OpenFile = new XtraOpenFileDialog();
     //   //
        OpenFile.FileName = "";
                   OpenFile.Title = "Photo:";
                  OpenFile.Filter = "Image files: (*.jpg)|*.jpg| 
 (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|(*.png)|*.png|(*.Gif)|*.Gif|(*.bmp)|*.bmp| All Files 
(*.*)|*.*";
                  DialogResult res = OpenFile.ShowDialog();
                  if (res == DialogResult.OK)
                   {
                       this.pictureStudent.Image = 
 System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OpenFile.FileName);
                   }
            #endregion
            //resize image
            if (pictureStudent.Image != null)
            {
                using (Bitmap currentImage = pictureStudent.EditValue as 
Bitmap)
                {
                    Bitmap savedImage = new Bitmap(currentImage, 
pictureStudent.ClientSize.Width, pictureStudent.ClientSize.Height);
                    savedImage.Save(txtStudentNumber.Text + ".jpg");
                    pictureStudent.Image = savedImage;
                    //  currentImage.Dispose();

                    //invoke the pictureEdit copy image 
                    //the name can be on of the following values:
```

OnClickedLoad;OnClickedSave;OnClickedCut;OnClickedCopy;OnClickedPaste;OnClickedDelete
                        InvokeMenuMethod(GetMenu(pictureStudent), 
    "OnClickedCopy"); //save image to clipboard

```
                    //save image from clipboard
                    if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
                    {
                        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                        string destinationDirectory = 
Properties.Settings.Default.StudentsPhotosDirectory;

                        if (destinationDirectory == null)
                        {
                            destinationDirectory = "C:\\Students - 
Photos\\";
                            bool exists = 
System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Students - Photos\\");
                            if (!exists)

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Students - Photos\\");
                        }

                        if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(destinationDirectory + "\\" + 
txtStudentNumber.Text + "." + ".jpg"))
                            {

XtraMessageBox.Show(LocRM.GetString("strImageAlreadySaved"));
                            }

                            Image image = 
(Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
                            image.Save(destinationDirectory + "\\" + 
txtStudentNumber.Text + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


                        }
                        else
                        {

XtraMessageBox.Show(LocRM.GetString("strNoImageClipboard"));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

XtraMessageBox.Show(LocRM.GetString("strClipboardEmpty"));
                    }
```

Comment: You may try to debug the actual path value where you try to save an image. Make sure it's correct on target PC. Second, make sure your process have permissions to write to destination folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The actual path is correct in the target PC, I think maybe the problem could be permissions. In the same computer in visual studio debug it works well and create files,but in release installed software it create errors. Can the permission be different in released software? How can I set the permission? before I build the software? I am running as an administrator both in development and in released.

Comment: As you receive ExternalException,[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_) states where are two possible reasons for that. Try to add `ImageFormat.Jpeg` as a second parameter and make absolutely sure that you save to not the file you was read from. Permissions shouldn't be a reason after your comment makes details more clear.